# ACF Fields not displaying on Product Tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, advanced-custom-fields

I've added ACF to our existing site which is using a highly customized child theme.

On my new field group I set the location rule as Post Taxonomy which is equal to the product_tag value ("classic"). However, these custom fields are not displaying or present.

I thought that custom fields could be enabled via "screen options" however screen options is not present on the product_tag taxonomy page.

I also disabled all plugins with the exception of elementor, ACF and woocommerce. Also with the same result.

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolved this?

Comment: could you show a screenshot of your acf fields group settings ?

Comment: Ive included a ascreengrab

Comment: weird. have you tried to show the fields on a more "classic" page like "Pages" or "Posts", just to see if it appears on it. If it appears, we can be sure that the problem is related to the post taxonomy or your rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a solution that would add custom meta via functions.php to woocommerce product tags and categories.

```
add_action('product_tag_add_form_fields', 'dr_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 1);
add_action('product_tag_edit_form_fields', 'dr_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 1);

//Product Tag Create page
function dr_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    ?>   
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="dr_elementor_template"><?php _e('Elementor Shortcode', 'wh'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="dr_elementor_template" id="dr_elementor_template">
    </div>
    <?php
}

//Product Tag Edit page
function dr_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    $dr_elementor_template = get_term_meta($term_id, 'dr_elementor_template', true);
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="dr_elementor_template"><?php _e('Elementor Shortcode', 'wh'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="dr_elementor_template" id="dr_elementor_template" value="<?php echo esc_attr($dr_elementor_template) ? esc_attr($dr_elementor_template) : ''; ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action('edited_product_tag', 'dr_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 1);
add_action('create_product_tag', 'dr_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 1);

// Save extra taxonomy fields callback function.
function dr_save_taxonomy_custom_meta($term_id) {
    $dr_elementor_template = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dr_elementor_template');
    update_term_meta($term_id, 'dr_elementor_template', $dr_elementor_template);
}
```

Where the taxonomy term slug that is associated with the taxonomy could be: Post Categories => category, Post Tag => post_tag, WC Product Categories => product_cat, WC Product Tags => product_tag